# AJAX doesn't automatically update before button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a conversation system where 2 people can chat with each other. I've made an AJAX function which updates the DIV box containing the messages every 2 seconds.

This is working as intended, **after** a user have written a message. Why isn't the AJAX call being run right away?

```
// SET AUTORUN updateMessages() EVERY 2 SECONDS
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval
    window.onload = function(){
        interval = setInterval('updateMessages()', 2000);
    };
});

// UPDATE #mail_container_conversation
function updateMessages() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>mail/ajaxupdate/<?php echo $user; ?>",
        data: dataString,
         
        success: function(data){
            $("#mail_container_conversation").html(data);
        }        
    });
}


// SEND NEW MESSAGE
$(function(){
    $("#mail_send").submit(function(){
        dataString = $("#mail_send").serialize();
         
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>mail/send",
        data: dataString,
         
        success: function(data){
            updateMessages();
            $(".mail_conversation_answer_input").val('');
        }
                  
        });
                 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Just in case. keep in mind that the first Call will be after the first interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide functions instead of strings to `setTimeout`/`setInterval` functions. And also there's no need for you to set interval on window load event. You can just keep it as part of DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
    updateMessages(); // don't wait 2 seconds for first update
    setInterval(updateMessages, 2000); // update every 2 seconds
});
```

Everything else seems to should work as expected **as long as your posback work when no data is being received** (ref `dataString`).

I hope you do realise that you're using implied globals and understand why that may be a big problem (ref `dataString` again).

### How I would rewrite your code

I would rewrite your whole code into the following that removes implied global variable `dataString`, doesn't pollute global scope with additional functions and uses `setTimeout` instead of interval which may in some cases be problematic (although in your case since it' only runs every 2 seconds it shouldn't be a problem if there's no additional very complex client-side script execution)

I've kept everything within function closure local scope:

```
$(function() {

    var timeout = null;

    var form = $("#mail_send").submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(".mail_conversation_answer_input", form).val("");
        updateMessages();
    });

    var updateMessages = function() {

        // we don'w want submit to interfere with auto-updates
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>mail/send",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#mail_container_conversation").html(data);
                timeout = setTimeout(updateMessages, 2000);
            }
        });
    };

    // start updating
    updateMessages();

});
```

This code requires your server side (processing on `/mail/send`) to understand that when nothing is being posted (no data) that it doesn't add empty line in the conversation but rather knows that this is just an update call. This functionality now uses only one server-side URL and not two of them. If you'd still require two, then this code should do the trick:

```
$(function() {

    var timeout = null;
    var url = {
        update: "<?php echo site_url();?>mail/ajaxupdate/<?php echo $user;?>",
        submit: "<?php echo site_url();?>mail/send",
        use: "update"
    };

    var form = $("#mail_send").submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        url.use = "submit";
        $(".mail_conversation_answer_input", form).val("");
        updateMessages();
    });

    var updateMessages = function() {

        // we don'w want submit to interfere with auto-updates
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url[url.use],
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#mail_container_conversation").html(data);
                url.use = "update";
                timeout = setTimeout(updateMessages, 2000);
            }
        });
    };

    // start updating
    updateMessages();

});
```

Comment: I've now removed the `POST` and `dataString` lines from the code, and it seems to work.

What is the problem you are talking about? I'm fairly new to all this ajax stuff

Comment: It's not Ajax stuff. It's Javascript stuff. Try to read about *implied globals* in the web...

Comment: You've misunderstood the code I'm afraid - the `#mail_send` form is actually posting a new message, it has nothing to do with the `updateMessages` function

Comment: @PatrickReck: I think you've misunderstood your code, as `updateMessages` uses variable `dataString` populated after form is being submitted.

Comment: I've removed the `dataString` as stated above. As far as I can see in your code, submitting the `#mail_send` form will run `updateMessages`

Comment: @PatrickReck: I've changed my code rewrite a bit to remove intervals and rather use *cacelling timeouts*. Timeouts will fire as expected and will be overriden on submits. This way your updates will happen every 2 second or when user hits submit and then continue on 2 second timeouts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23295/discussion-between-patrick-reck-and-robert-koritnik)

Comment: @PatrickReck: I've added an additional rewrite if you still require two URL which in my opinion should not be the case as both return the same thing. It's just that one also processes any incoming data.

Comment: @PatrickReck: due to security policy I' can't access chat so you'll have to provide your question here as comment. Just try to be as precise and thorough as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If the rest of your code work, the problem probably is withing this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval
    window.onload = function(){
        interval = setInterval('updateMessages()', 2000);
    };
});
```

1. There is no need to attach it to `window.onload`, since you already wrapped it in a DOM-ready callback.
2. Remove the single-quotes and the parenthesis from within your call to `setInterval`
3. The DOM-ready callback can be shorten, by just passing a function to the jQuery-method.

Try this instead:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(updateMessages, 2000);
});
```

**Further improvements - Avoid intervals with AJAX:**

When dealing with AJAX, you should avoid using intervals, as you may end up stacking calls to the server, if the server takes more than two seconds to respond. `setInterval` will not care if your server had time to respond or not, it will keep calling it every 2 seconds no matter what.

I suggest that you use a timeout instead, and start a new timeout in the complete-callback of the Ajax-call.

In your case, it could look something like this:

```
$(function () {
    // Make the first call immediately when the DOM is ready
    updateMessage();
});

function updateMessages() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>mail/ajaxupdate/<?php echo $user; ?>",
        data: dataString,

        success: function(data){
            $("#mail_container_conversation").html(data);
            // Make a new call, 2 seconds after you've 
            // received a successful respose
            setTimeout(updateMessages, 2000);
        }        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `updateMessages()` tries to send `datastring` to the server, but this doesn't get filled in until the `.submit()` function runs.

I don't know what you should put in there, since I don't know what the `mail/ajaxupdate` script expects. If this is called when nothing happens, I suspect no form data is needed at all, so you can give an empty string.

I'll bet if you checked the Javascript console you'd see some error messages about trying to serialize `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

give a try with

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval('updateMessages()', 2000);

});
```

Comment: `setInterval( updateMessages, 2000 );` would be slightly better. No need to pass a string here and call on the internal eval routines.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `window.onload` in your document ready call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('updateMessages()', 2000);
});
```

That should be enough to get it started.

As it is now, once the DOM is ready, you're then asking it to wait for the window to load.. but by that point it's already loaded, so nothing happens.